# Direct Product, and Subdirect Product in Herstein text

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

I'm reading *Noncommutative Rings* by *I. N. Herstein*. And I find one lemma pretty strange. It's on page 52 of the book. I'm typing everything necessary all here, so everyone can have a look at it.

**Definition of direct product**

> Given a family of rings $\{ R_\gamma \}$, for $\gamma \in I$, where *I* is some index set. We define the *direct product*, or *completely direct sum* of $\{ R_\gamma \}$ to be:
> $$\prod_{\gamma \in I} R_\gamma = \left\{f:I \to \bigcup_{\gamma \in I} R_\gamma \middle|f(\gamma)\in R_\gamma, \forall \gamma \in I \right\}$$

**Definition of subdirect product**

> *R* is said to be a *subdirect product* of the rings $\{R_\gamma\}_{\gamma \in I}$ if there exists a monomorphism $\phi: R \to \prod\limits_{\gamma \in I} R_\gamma$, such that $\pi_\gamma\phi(R) = R_\gamma, \forall \gamma \in I$, where $\pi_\gamma$ is the projection of $\prod\limits_{\gamma \in I} R_\gamma$ onto $R_\gamma$.

---

Here comes the lemma that I don't really get.

> **Lemma 2.2.1**
>
> Let $R$ be a ring, and let $\phi_\gamma: R \to R_\gamma$ be homomorphism of $R$ **onto** rings $R_\gamma$. Let $U_\gamma = \text{ker }\phi_\gamma$. Then $R$ is a subdirect product of the $R_\gamma$ **if and only if** $\bigcap\limits_\gamma U_\gamma = 0$.

---

Herstein didn't give a proof to it. But the $\Leftarrow$ should be easy. I'm having trouble with the $\Rightarrow$, since i don't think it's correct at all. But after reading herstein's book for a while, I come to realize that his wording is very **dense**, and there are times when something appears false on the first read, but when think about it for a while, it turns out to be so true.

Here's my counter-example of the lemma, so if someone can have a look at it, I would be very please.

---

**Counter example**

Consider the index set $I$ to have only 1 element. And consider the ring $R = \prod\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$, $R$ can be thought of as the direct product of itself (i.e $R = \prod\limits_{i \in I} R$, since $I$ has cardinality of 1), as well as subdirect product of itself (with the injection $\phi$ being the identity).

Now I let $\phi: R \to R$ sends each element $(a_1; a_2; a_3; ...) \in \prod\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ to $(a_2; a_3; ...) \in \prod\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$. Of course $\phi$ is a ring epimorphism. But  $\text{ker }\phi \cong \mathbb{Z} \neq 0$.

---

What I'm trying to show above is that even though $R$ **is** the subdirect product of $R$, I can construct $\phi$ (stands for $\phi_\gamma$'s in the lemma), such that $\text{ker } \phi \neq 0$ (stands for $\bigcap_\gamma \text{ker } \phi_\gamma$).

Am I missing something here? Is there any way to prove the $\Rightarrow$ direction?

I can prove the $\Rightarrow$ direction if it states that there **exists** a set of $\phi_\gamma$'s instead of $\phi_\gamma$'s being **chosen randomly**. Or am I misunderstanding Herstein's ideas?

Thank you guys very much,

And have a good day.

---

Here's an online version of the book: http://books.google.com/books?id=hXa7mVyZCzYC&printsec=frontcover&hl=vi&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

---

**Edit**

If the above theorem needs to be rephrased then, I don't really get the author's idea on page 53:

> "On the other hand, suppose that R is a subdirect product of the rings $R_\phi = R / U_\phi$. Therefore, $\bigcap U_\phi = 0$."

I'm not sure, but how can he deduce this fact? It's illegal to use the canonical epimorphisms $\pi_\phi: R \to R / U_\phi$ to conclude that $\bigcap U_\phi = \bigcap \text{ker }\pi_\phi = 0$, right? Because, not EVERY set of epimorphisms $f_\phi: R \to R/U_\phi$ will satisfy the conditions that $\bigcap \text{ker }f_\phi = 0$. There exists some set that does, but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

But I'm pretty sure that what Herstein **meant** to say was that $R$ is a subdirect product of the $R_\gamma$ **using the map $\phi:R\to\prod\limits_{\gamma\in I}R_\gamma$ induced by the $\phi_\gamma$ as the monomorphism in the definition of subdirect product** if and only if the intersection of kernels is zero.

Comment: But there's something that still confuses me. On page 53 of the book, the last paragraph, Herstein says that "On the other hand, suppose that $R$ is a subdirect sum of the rings $R_\phi = R / U_\phi$. Therefore, $\bigcap U_\phi = 0$." How come? Is he assuming that EVERY set of epimorphisms $f_\phi: R \to R / U_\phi$ has $\bigcap \text{ker } f_\phi = 0$. And the canonical projections $\pi_\phi : R \to R / U_\phi$ form one of those sets, hence $\bigcap U_\phi = \bigcap \text{ker }\pi_\phi = 0$. But this is not true, right? @@

Comment: Again, strictly speaking you're correct. Here he means that the canonical projections express $R$ as a subdirect product. The data that defines a subdirect product is a ring $R$ **together with** a family of surjections $R\to R_\gamma$ such that $\dots$, and it would be more precise to define a subdirect product as that whole collection of data.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the delay, after like 1 day of searching, and thinking. I think I get what you mean. Thank you so much. :*

Answer (score 1):

You did not take into account the condition
$$\pi_\gamma\phi(R) = R_\gamma, \forall \gamma \in I.$$
In your case $\pi_\gamma={\rm id}$, so $\phi(R) = R.$ But in the definition it is required that $\phi$ to be an monomorphism.

Comment: Do you mean 'just of the rings $R_\gamma$', or 'just of the ring $R_\gamma$'?

Comment: 'just of the rings $R_\gamma$'.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused. I just don't see where my mistake is. In my example $I$ (i.e the index set) has cardinality of 1. And $R$ can be thought of as the subdirect product of itself $R = R$. But it doesn't mean that EVERY $\phi: R \to R$ must be monic.

Comment: Sorry, I will correct my answer.

Comment: $R$ is indeed a subdirect product of $R$, with $\text{id}: R \to R$, and of course, since $I$ only have index 1, $\pi_\gamma$ is the same as the identity map, so $\pi_\gamma \text{id}(R) = \text{id}\text{id}(R) = R$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understood correctly your counterexample: you take the product of $\,\Bbb Z\;$ with itself just once, i.e. we get $\,\Bbb Z\,$ itself, both as a direct and as a semidirect product according to Herstein's definitions.

If so, I can't see how your defined $\,\phi\,$ works since an element of the direct product $\,R=\Bbb Z\,$ in this case is just a $\,1-$ton "vector" $\,(n)\,$ , i.e.: there are no $\,(a_1,a_2,...)\,$ as there is only one single coordinate!

Thus, for your function $\,\phi\,$ to work it must be the injection $\,(n)\mapsto n\;$ , which kernel indeed is zero, as promised by the theorem in Herstien's....

Comment: I'm sorry for my confusing wording. But no, I take the product of $\mathbb{Z}$ infinitely countably many times, and let $R$ denotes that ring. Then $R$ can be viewed as a subdirect product of $R$ (i.e, of itself). The index set $I$ applies for $R$, but not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ok, I edited my original post to make it clearer. I'm so sorry for not being very clear. :(

Comment: I still don't get it, @user49685: you clearly write in your post "consider the index set I to have only one element", and this means we're taking the cartesian product of a set *once*, i.e. the set itself...what am I missing here?

Comment: Yes, what I mean is we take the cartesian product of the set $R$ once, not $\mathbb{Z}$, and $R$ is defined as $R = \prod\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$. The subdirect product ring I consider here is $R$, not $\mathbb{Z}$. $\mathbb{Z}$ is only used to construct $R$.

Comment: Oooh, I see now! Let me check what I wrote under this new light...

Comment: Thanks man. If my counterexample is fine, can you take a look at the question at the end of my original post? Thanks. :*